# On the induced contradiction in Theorem 10.3.4 of Stein & Shakarchi's complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

The statement of the theorem is as follows:

**Theorem(10.3.4)**: Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on the upper half-plane satisfying:

1. $f(\tau+2)=f(\tau)$,
2. $f(-1/\tau)=f(\tau)$,
3. $f(\tau)$ is bounded.
   Then $f$ is a constant.

Assume in contrary $f$ is not constant, based on the periodicity and relation (2), we can restrict our attention to the fundamental domain $\mathcal{F}$ of the shape

[image].

Using properties 1-3, one will be able to show that by maximum modulus principle,
$$\lim_{\text{Im}(\tau)\to\infty}|f(\tau)|<\sup_{\tau\in\mathcal{F}}|f(\tau)|,\;\;\;\lim_{\text{Im}(\tau)\to\infty}|f(1-1/\tau)|<\sup_{\tau\in\mathcal{F}}|f(\tau)|.$$
Then, in the end of the proof, they seems claimed the second inequality above will implies that **$f$ will attains maximum in the interior of the upper half-plane**, contradicting the maximum modulus principle.

I am confused at this point. Why was that?